# Limit max rows select for one of OR statements

Tags: sql, conditional-statements

I'm trying to get some data from SQL data table with multiple OR conditions.
Lets say I have 10 rows in table named products.

My query

```
SELECT * FROM products 
WHERE product_name = 'nice' OR
product_second_name = 'pretty'
LIMIT 10
```

Is there any way to select 5 products meeting first condition and another 5 products meeting second condition if table contains 10 products called 'nice' ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to do 2 separate queries with a UNION:

```
(SELECT * FROM products 
WHERE product_second_name = 'pretty'
LIMIT 10)
UNION
(SELECT * FROM products 
WHERE product_name = 'nice'
LIMIT 5)
```

However, then you have to distinguish duplicates via DISTINCT or some other mechanism. You have to define what happens if a product_name is nice and the product_second_name is pretty (in your original query, the product would appear once)